# Object Destucturing Inner Functions Syntax

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I understand that object destructuring makes `console.log(occupation)` equivalent to `console.log(luke.occupation)`

```
let luke = { occupation: 'jedi', father: 'anakin' };
let {occupation, father} = luke;

console.log(occupation); // 'jedi'
console.log(father); // 'anakin'
```

However I do not understand what the equivalent to `console.log(getState())` is below without object destructuring as `console.log(makeState.getState())` does not make sense.

```
function makeState() {
  let state: number
  function getState() {
    return state
  }
  function setState(x: number) {
    state = x
  }
  return { getState, setState }
}

const { getState, setState } = makeState()
setState(1)
console.log(getState()) // 1
setState(2)
console.log(getState()) // 2
```

What is the equivalent of `console.log(getState())` without using the object destructuring syntax?

Comment: `const state = makeState()` and then use  `state.getState()`. Destructuring is just getting the properties to a variable. `makeState` returns an object with a `getState` property.

Comment: Why would `const { getState, setState } = makeState()` create another `const` named `state`?

Comment: What @adiga said. 
When ever you run `makeState()` you will create a new state on that variable.

You can also create it and get it immediately like: `makeState().getState()` this will return 0, since that is the default value of a number.

Comment: Your code won't create a `state` variable. I just added the how the code would look without the destrucuturing syntax.

Comment: @ElijahLee if you run `const state = makeState()` you will be able to call `state.getState()` because that is what you named the variable with `makeState()`.

You could also do it like: `const foo = makeState()` and then `foo.getState()` it just depends on what you call the variable.

Comment: Or maybe use a different variable name like `const obj = makeState()` if you get confused with the  `state` variable inside the function

Comment: @Bjørn Nyborg Is that how the javascript compiler interprets it?

Comment: @ElijahLee This is valid javascript, so it doesn't need any compilation.

But if you for example transpile it for IE support, babel default would transpile it like this: `var _makeState = makeState(),
  getState = _makeState.getState,
  setState = _makeState.setState;`

Comment: You can test it on [babel](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmBlKqqYAUAlIgN4BQiiANplIgM54FWKiSwKIDm9u-IqUrVqAJ3ogxSZoLYBfNh2jwZ_FkQAewttVkFEAXkSaFbCVClIyvdYIA0TOwcWKKEBM3K2oAgo8ZnTER5IxQMHA0SCkDfKIBGYndPODoAOho4HkI-OMESYiA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=script&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Ces2015&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.12.9&externalPlugins=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrong in the part that destructuring makes `occupation` equivalent to `luke.occupation`. They both return `'jedi'`, until...

```
let luke = { occupation: 'jedi', father: 'anakin' };
let {occupation, father} = luke;

console.log(occupation); // 'jedi'
luke.occupation = 'noLongerJedi'
console.log(occupation); // 'jedi'
console.log(luke.occupation); // 'noLongerJedi'
```

So, as you can see, destructuring copies *the current value of the destructured property* into the variable, but nothing more than that.

It's basically syntactic sugar for

```
let occupation = luke.occupation
let father = luke.father
```

In your second case, the same happens.

The `setState` and `getState` properties of an object returned by `makeState` get assigned to the `setState` and `getState` variables.

The magic that they point to the same state, is in the functions themselves: they both receive a closure scope from their parent, `makeState`, and as they are from the same call to `makeState`, they access the same closure.

So, to answer your question anyway, you can think of this code like...

```
const _temp = makeState()
const setState = _temp.setState
const getState = _temp.getState
```

...without having a `_temp` variable.